# Colimits in the category of suplattices

Tags: ct.category-theory, galois-theory, lattice-theory, locales

I want to compute coequalizers in the category $\mathcal{S}up$ of complete lattices and $\bigvee$-preserving maps. One way (I think?) is to use the dual equivalence

$$
\mathcal{Sup} \leftrightarrows \mathcal{S}up^{op}
$$
which (going forward) takes $M \mapsto M^{op}$ and $f: M \to N$ to the right adjoint, denoted $f_{\ast}: N^{op} \to M^{op}$ which is the same as a $\bigwedge$-preserving map $N \to M$.

Forming limits in $\mathcal{S}up$ is relatively easy. Products are product posets equipped with projection maps $p_i: \prod_{j \in J} M_j \to M_i$; the universal property is easy. The equalizer of $f,g: M\rightrightarrows N$ is just
$$
E =  \{x \in M : f(x) = g(x) \}.
$$
with a universal property from inclusion of $E$ (a complete lattice) into $M$.

Coporoducts are again Cartesian products, but with inclusion maps $q_i^{\ast}: M_i \to \coprod_{j \in J} M_i$ that are *left* adjoint to the projection maps $p_i$.

Now, I'm trying to understand coequalizers. Chapter 1 of Joyal's [*An Extension of the Galois Theory of Grothendieck*](http://www.ams.org/books/memo/0309/) says the following:

[image: Joyal, An Extension of the Galois Theory of Grothendieck, Chapter 1]

Here is some backgroud. in $\mathcal{S}up$, a congruence relation is an equivalence relation such that $x_i~R~y$ for all $i \in I$ implies $$\left( \bigvee_{i \in I} x_i \right)~R~y $$
Not entirely sure what an "equivalence relation generated by a subset" is here...

My question is: how do you obtain an "explicit calculation" of coequalizers from Proposition 3? What am I missing?

Comment: The equivalence relation generated by a relation $R$ is the smallest equivalence relation $S$ such that $R\subseteq S$, i.e., the intersection of all the equivalence relations that include $R$ as a subset. The congruence relation generated by $R$ is defined analogously. I would expect that the coequalizer of two morphisms $f,g:A\to B$ is the quotient of $B$ by the congruence relation generated by the set of all pairs $(f(a),g(a))$ for $a\in A$.

Comment: Yes, I see this, but I wonder if this is isomorphic to the set of $b \in B$ such that $f^{\ast}(b) = g^{\ast}(b)$?? That is, can coequalizers in $\mathcal{S}up$ be written as equalizers in $\mathcal{I}nf$??